# Animate a Grid column layout at the touch of a button on windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Good day, 
i would like to create a slide in and out animation for a grid layout column that contains a set of items. When a button is pressed, it slides in and then slides out when an item contained in the grid is selected. An Example is just like the sliding options on a windows 8 PC when one hovers the mouse on the right of the screen. How do i get that effect?..  Thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: Have you tried a tutorial like this? http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/XNA-for-Silverlight-developers-Part-3-Animation-transforms.aspx

Comment: @NeilTurner Thanks.. sorry for the rather late reply. Will try that out!